# Why is my React Native Expo App stuck bundling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Fairly new with React-Native and JS. I've been creating a simple login screen, used to work and bundle in my phone with expo go app but after modifying a bit the App.js file when I type "npm start" it simple stays bundling forever unless I close VS code.

There are no additional dependencies or modifications besides what comes default when you create a folder with the `npx create-expo-app@latest <name>` command.

This is my App.js code

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [isPosting, setIsPosting] = useState(false)

  const validateForm = () => {
    let errors = {}

    if (!email) errors.email = "Email is required"
    if (!password) errors.password = "Password is required"

    setErrors(errors)

    return Object.keys(errors).length === 0;
  }

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if(validateForm()) {
      setIsPosting(true)
      console.log(email, password)
      const response = await fetch("IP", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password
        })
      })
      console.log("Submitted:", email, password)
      const newP = await response.json()
      console.log(newP)
      setEmail("");
      setPassword("");
      setErrors({});
      setIsPosting(false)
    }
  }
  return (
    // makes the keyboard not interferre with the container that hass the username and apssswords
    <KeyboardAvoidingView 
      behavior="padding" 
      keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 100 : -170} 
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View style={styles.form}>
        <Image source={require("icon location")} style={styles.image} />
        <Text style={styles.label}>E-mail</Text>
        <TextInput 
          style={styles.input} 
          placeholder='Enter your E-mail' 
          value={email} 
          onChangeText={setEmail}
        />
        {
          errors.email ? <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errors.email}</Text> : null
        }
        <Text style={styles.label}>Passsword</Text>
        <TextInput 
          style={styles.input} 
          placeholder='Enter your password' 
          secureTextEntry 
          value={password} 
          onChangeText={setPassword}
        />
        {
          errors.password ? <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errors.password}</Text> : null
        }
        <Button title={isPosting ? "Logging in..." : "Login"} onPress={handleSubmit} />
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: "f5f5f5"
  },

  form: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },

  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginBottom: 5,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "#ddd",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 15,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },

  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginBottom: 50,
  },

  errorText: {
    color: "red",
    marginBottom: 10,
  },

});
```

[How it looks in VS Code, will stay bundling as long as VS Code is open while consuming processing power. Every time it gets stuck at a different %](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3dqi.png)

Tried deleting the "node_modules" and "package-lock.json" files and then running npm install but still nothing.

Still quite new so don't know exactly all the tools I have available to find the source of the problem

Comment: [Mre] – if you strip this code down to an empty app, does the problem go away? If not, post that version of the code instead.

Comment: While stripping down the code I actually did find the issue. Something with the way I included an image to my container:
<Image source={require("icon location")} style={styles.image} />
Removed this line of code and it works perfectly again.

Thanks for the guidance!